# Preserve Xdebug exception handling when using own exception handler

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

I've written my own Exception and Error handlers in my PHP project.

However, when doing development, I would like to have XDebug do it's normal "exception" and "error" handling in addition to my own.

I've found that I can easily enough have XDebug continue to do "error" handling if my own error handler returns FALSE.  But I can't find a way to get a similar effect with "Exception" handling.

I was hoping I could manually call an XDebug function. xdebug_print_function_stack() is the closest thing I could see, but it won't give a true stack trace of the triggered exception.

Answer (score 3):

Xdebug adds a property to every *thrown* `Exception`, namely `xdebug_message`, which contains the contents of the table normally displayed by Xdebug.

So to visualize an exception with stacktrace as Xdebug, you could do something like the following:

```
try {
   $result = fetch();
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo '<table>' . $e->xdebug_message . '</table>';
}
```

And while searching for the documentation of `xdebug_message` I stumbled on a possible duplicate question: [Methods for an Xdebug Exception class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740240/methods-for-an-xdebug-exception-class)