# Methods for an Xdebug Exception class

Tags: php, xdebug

Is it possible to see the methods of the extended Exception class Xdebug creates? I want to get at the HTML formatted stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after hacking at it, there's no method like Niels showed but there's a public property called $exception->xdebug_message that has the HTML formatted message. Don't forget to wrap it in a table tag if you are placing it in a HTML page.

```
echo '<table>';
echo $exception->xdebug_message;
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the fancy HTML outputted trace:

```
ob_start();
xdebug_print_function_stack();
$myFancyHTMLOutput = ob_get_clean();
```

Pass the option `XDEBUG_STACK_NO_DESC` to leave out the header.

However, Xdebug does not actually patch visible methods into `Exception`, as evidenced by printing `get_class_methods($e)` inside an exception handler:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => string '__construct' (length=11)
  1 => string 'getMessage' (length=10)
  2 => string 'getCode' (length=7)
  3 => string 'getFile' (length=7)
  4 => string 'getLine' (length=7)
  5 => string 'getTrace' (length=8)
  6 => string 'getPrevious' (length=11)
  7 => string 'getTraceAsString' (length=16)
  8 => string '__toString' (length=10)
```

You can of course always format it yourself from the array returned by `getTrace`, but that has [nothing to do with Xdebug and is just built in functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php).

Comment: I was looking at that but that call doesn't give me the information from the exception. I'm capturing unhandled Exception and I want to get the stack at the time of the exception.

Comment: Keep in mind that options for  `xdebug_print_function_stack()` are only available since Xdebug 2.3. (is that version even released?) http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace#xdebug_print_function_stack