# PHP: Print caught exception like Xdebug

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

I have a PHP function which I call when I caught an exception. It accepts that exception as optional parameter, so it can show it for debugging purposes:

```
public static function notFound($resource, \Exception $exception = null) {
    // [... normal error handling ...]

    if (DEBUG && $exception != null) {
        echo '<br><br><h2>Stacktrace:</h2>';
        print_r($exception);          
    }
    die();
}
```

What I would like is to display this exception the same way uncaught exceptions and warnings are displayed with xdebug (styled with CSS and HTML, possibly with a different color scheme). Like this (created by `echo $exception->getTrace();`):

[image]

If I use `print_r($exception);` I get this, which seems to contain at least some of the needed output for xdebug:

[image]

I have tried `echo $exception->xdebug_message;`, `var_dump($exception);`, and `var_dump($exception->xdebug_message);`, but none of it worked. The last one seems to be the closed to what I want, but I can't get it to work correctly:

[image]

Is there a way to use xdebug styling for caught exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution in this list of [all xdebug functions](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions):

```
xdebug_print_function_stack($exception);
```

Comment: This will print the current stack, not the exception stack.

Answer (score 5):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768176/1286814.

In short, you just need to wrap `xdebug_message` inside a table:

```
echo '<table>'.$e->xdebug_message.'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of `xdebug` you can display caught (and uncaught) exceptions natively with:

```
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1
```

> integer xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
>
> When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will show a stack trace whenever
> an Exception or Error is raised - even if this Exception or Error is
> actually caught.
>
> Error 'exceptions' were introduced in PHP 7.

Or, if you only want to show errors (caught or uncaught), but not Exceptions, use this instead:

```
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
```

> integer xdebug.show_error_trace = 0
>
> When this setting is set to 1,
> Xdebug will show a stack trace whenever an Error is raised - even if
> this Error is actually caught.

https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#show_error_trace